# AWS CLI in CMD and PowerShell

Tags: python-3.x, windows, amazon-web-services, anaconda, aws-cli

On Win 10 I've installed Anaconda (via chocolatey) and the AWS CLI.  I can successfully issue commands via the AWS CLI as long as I'm in one of the following:

- an Anaconda prompt
- a Git Bash prompt
- the powershell terminal *inside of visual studio code*

However, when I try to issue commands from a "straight-up" CMD or PowerShell window, then I get errors:

```
C:\>aws s3 ls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\barias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\aws.cmd", line 50, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "C:\Users\barias\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 30, in <module>
    import botocore.credentials
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\credentials.py", line 34, in <module>
    from botocore.config import Config
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\config.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore.endpoint import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, MAX_POOL_CONNECTIONS
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 22, in <module>
    from botocore.awsrequest import create_request_object
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\awsrequest.py", line 26, in <module>
    import botocore.utils
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 7, in <module>
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py)
```

I am not a Python programmer, so it is not self-evident what this error means.

A side commentary on my Anaconda install:

> I am surprised to see Anaconda installed in `C:\tools`.  I think that is because (1) my chocolatey script which installed Anaconda was executed inside that folder and (2) the Anaconda chocolatey package perhaps was designed to install in the current working directory?  Regardless, I don't think this problem is a result of where Anaconda is installed.
>
> I also found that I had to manually put the python exe onto the path.  I'm not sure why the Anaconda install didn't do that for me.

As it turns out, I can successfully issue terraform commands from CMD or PowerShell to that same AWS account.  I would have thought if the AWS CLI wasn't working, then terraform would be hosed as well.  Weird.

None of the prompts (Git Bash, Anaconda, CMD, PowerShell) have `PYTHONPATH` OR `PYTHONHOME` environment variables set.  The Anaconda path has these environment variables:

```
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CONDA_EXE=C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_PREFIX=C:\tools\Anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base) 
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\tools\Anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_SHLVL=1
```

I tried setting these in the CMD window, but it did not fix the problem.  Also, the Git Bash prompt successfully handles the AWS CLI...and it doesn't have any environment variables configured regarding python or "conda".

Any ideas of why I'm getting this error?  Remember, it works fine as long as I execute commands from an Anaconda prompt.

Comment: Compare PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME in the working and non-working environment.

Comment: @jarmod I've updated my question with info about those and other vars.